# Pandas remove cell content if has less than specific number of characters

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have the following  pandas dataframe:

```
>>>name    location   problems
0  Lena    Haifa      ,,
1  Layla   Aman       not enough points
2  Dili    Istanbul   ,
...
```

I would like to change the cell content if it has less than 5 letters,
so I'll get this table:

```
>>>name    location   problems
0  Lena    Haifa      
1  Layla   Aman       not enough points
2  Dili    Istanbul   
...
```

(remvove the , )

How can  I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way using `np.where`:

```
df['problems'] = np.where(df['problems'].str.len() < 5, '', df['problems'])
print(df)

    name  location           problems
0   Lena     Haifa                   
1  Layla      Aman  not enough points
2   Dili  Istanbul
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
df.loc[df['problems'].str.len()<5,'problems'] = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].where(df['col'].str.len() >= 5)
```

or if you want an empty string instead of `NaN`:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].where(df['col'].str.len() >= 5, other='')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use assign function:

```
df = df.assgin(problem = lambda x: np.where(x['problem'].str.len()< 5,'',x['problem']))
```